# How do I define an empty Fern type used in a union?

Tags: types

I have a union type I want to use to hold a success and failure result, but I don't *yet* know the properties of the success result and want to give myself the flexibility to use them later on.  I want to go ahead and define the types for both results however and make it easy to add more properties in the future.

My thinking is the type definition would look like so:

```yaml
types: 
  SuccessType: {} 

  FailureType: 
    properties: 
      reason: str
  ResultType:
    union:
      success: SuccessType
      failure: FailureType
```

... but I don't know if there's a better way to accomplish this to give myself flexibility in the properties of the `SuccessType` later on?

Answer (score 0):

While the above gives a compile error, you can instead define the success type but specify it doesn't have any properties, like so:

```yaml
types: 
  SuccessType:
    properties: {}

  FailureType: 
    properties: 
      reason: string
  ResultType:
    union:
      success: SuccessType
      failure: FailureType
```

This definition of the type with no properties will now allow you to add properties in the future with the type already in place!